# Jquery filtering list

Tags: jquery, toggle, filtering, show-hide

I`m having difficult to solve this problem.

```
<ul>
      <li class="complete">list item 1
            <ul>
                  <li class="complete">list item 1</li>
                  <li class="pending">list item 2
            <ul>
      </li>
      <li class="complete">list item 2
            <ul>
                  <li class="complete">list item 1</li>
                  <li class="complete">list item 2
            <ul>
      </li>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I`m trying to solve is that I have 2 checkbox complete and pending now if I uncheck complete all the list with complete class will hide "BUT" if it has a sublist and that sublist has pending class that parent list will remain visible else it will hide.

I hope somebody can help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: what have u tried till now? can u post ur JS pls? It'll help us help u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jquery code :

```
$('.complete').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.pending').length) {
        $(this).css({display: 'block'})
    } else {
        $(this).css({display: 'none'})
    }
})
```

Comment: wow awesome, this is very much helpful. thanks Lucas and Hungerpain. very quick response love it

Comment: still don't have enough reputation to give a vote but awesome solution.

Comment: Thanks. Otherwise, you can validate my answer, clicking on the "V" under the down arrow.